# Как запушить во второй аккаунт git

Tags: git, git-push

подскажите, пожалуйста, к локальному репозиторию подключены 2 аккаунта Git

Я внёс изменения, но хочу запушить только в один из них...
Как это сделать?
git push -u и.... как выбрать аккаунт в который внести изменения?

Comment: вы ни разу не пушили? `git remote` - выдаст вам имена удалённых. и потом `git push _имя_удалённого_ _имя_ветки_` всё сделает

Comment: Если бы. Я добавляю >git remote add origin - добавляется нормально команда git remote - выдаёт origin если пушить как вы напиасали - ошибка  invalid refspec

Comment: значит удаляете `git remote remove origin`. И создаёте правильно `git remote add _имя_ _адрес_` *Вы в вопросе говорили, что у вас два удалённых??*

Comment: Если удаленных репозиториев два, то один из них должен называться не origin, а как-то по-другому.